# Decision to return Local or Remote

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, jndi

I have a simple bean declared as follows

```
 @Local(LocalInt.class)
 @Remote(RemoteInt.class)
 @Stateless(name="name")
 public MyEJB_Implementation {
    //methods
 }
```

As you can see, it is a single bean that has a local interface (for local clients) and a remote interface (for remote ones).

The clients (remote and local) retrieve the instance as follows:

```
ctx = new InitialContext(environment);
ctx.lookup("name");
```

How does the Container decide if it will deliver a proxy implementing the `LocalInt` interface or the `RemoteInt` interface? (as I am using the very same "name" for the lookup).

I mean, does the JNDI registry know somehow whether the lookup is done in the same JVM or from a remote server?

And also, doesn't this distinction (for local and remote invokations) collide whith the semantics of "lookup"? (which should have exactly zero or one object registered for one name, in this case there seems to be 2 objects (local and remote) under the same name).

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience the container will return the`local` interface when the clients are in the same container (EAR or WAR) and when outside of it will return the`remote` interface.

I'm not sure it's stated as a requirement in the Java EE specs, but nearly all standard containers behave this way (again, in my experience)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that is the result, but I am interested in the mechanism, i am doing a lookup that is returning a diferent object based on the fact that it comes from the same JVM or a remote one... shouldn't JNDI be based just in names?

Answer (score 1):

The EJB container will bind the local and remote interfaces to distinct JNDI names, so it depends which one you look up.  For example, in EJB 3.1, the standard binding locations would be something like this:

```
java:app/YourEJBModule/YourEJBName!com.your.pkg.LocalInt
java:app/YourEJBModule/YourEJBName!com.your.pkg.RemoteInt
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see your point, but in the code I am doing the manual lookup with the name "name" (for both remote and local), how does the container (the JNDI registry, in this case) know if I am in the same JVM or in a remote one to choose the LocalInt or the RemoteInt?

Comment: I don't know.  Perhaps the application server is returning an object that implements all the interfaces for convenience?  What application server are you using?  Assuming `o = ctx.lookup(...)`, what does `o.getClass()` and `java.util.Arrays.toString(o.getClass().getInterfaces())` return?

Answer (score 0):

Jndi is highly contextual. Even if you think you're using absolute names, they are often relative to the current component you're doing the lookup from.

I'm surprised that "name" works. This is actually intended for a different namespace (non-JNDI).

Comment: Interesting, do you mean that JNDI behave differently depending on the invoker? this is absolutely not the way other naming services (DNS, filesystem...) work... i have doubts, i checked a bit and i didn't see any reference to this behaviour... would you have one? Thank you!

Comment: File systems have the concept of relative paths as well. Your location in the tree determines the outcome of say "cd foo". "java:comp" for instance resolves to the private JNDI tree of a component (last one on the stack). Eg with beans A and B, doing a lookup for "java:comp/env/foo" may return a different thing when called from code inside A vs B. Even "worse", calling java:whatever on a remote JNDI context, will still resolve locally and NOT at the remote location, since "java:" always points to the local context.

Answer (score 0):

EJB 3.1 specification in section 3 explains Local and Remote Views clearly. In section 3.3.2 it says

> Session beans may have local clients. A local client is a client that
>   is collocated in the same JVM with the session bean that provides the
>   local client view and which may be tightly coupled to the bean. A
>   local client of a session bean may be another enterprise bean or a web
>   component. Access to an enterprise bean through the local client view
>   requires the collocation in the same JVM of both the local client and
>   the enterprise bean that provides the local client view. The local
>   client view therefore does not provide the location transparency
>   provided by the remote client view. Access to an enterprise bean
>   through the local client view is only required to be supported for
>   local cli- ents packaged within the same application as the enterprise
>   bean that provides the local client view. Compliant implementations of
>   this specification may optionally support access to the local client
>   view of an enterprise bean from a local client packaged in a different
>   application.

That should explain the behaviour

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't explain that the JNDI is returning a diferent object depending on whether the caller is local or remote. Is JNDI supposed to behave differently deppending on the caller?